# Is it possible to optimize image that i get from backend with nuxt/image?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to compress images that I get from the backend with `nuxt-image`. When I want to change the format, for example to `webp`, the path is incorrect.

If you have any suggestions let me know, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://image.nuxtjs.org/components/nuxt-img#format

So you can do something like this:

```
<nuxt-img src="imagePath" width="500" height="500" format="webp" />
```

This will take care of the format conversion and update the path accordingly.